# Как в Axate реализовать вложенный запрос?

Tags: sql

Как этот запрос реализовать в Axapte?

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM rec JOIN (
  SELETC max(date) d, id FROM rec
  WHERE
  `Date`<"2014-02-03 00:00:00"
  GROUP BY id
) drec ON rec.id = drec.id AND rec.date = drec.d
WHERE
  rec.value<>0;
```

Comment: Axapte, это что-то проприетарное?

Comment: Э... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_AX ? Вы написали слово двумя разными способами, гугл предлагает третий.

Comment: Это Microsoft Dynamics AX а там язык программирования x++